# Socket.io detect disconnect reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io,can I detect the disconnect reason from disconnect event ? I can see in log files like this

info: transport end (booted)
info: transport end (close timeout)
info: transport end (error)

I want to get the reason (booted,close timeout,error) I will use like this:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
   console.log('User 1 disconnected because '+reason);
});
```

Can I get the reason ?

EDIT:I found the solution

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(reason){
   console.log('User 1 disconnected because '+reason);
});
```

Comment: If you found your solution, post it as a answer and accept and mark it as solved; this is for people in the future looking for the same answer.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for the user leaving the page?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(reason){
   console.log('User 1 disconnected because '+reason);
});
```

This is the solution.

Possible reasons for disconnect are [now documented](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api#event-disconnect).

Comment: You should list down the reasons with explanations instead of just put a link to another website, because that website won't be found later just like your given link.

Answer (score 3):

@Sarith Nob - The link is broken, and archive.org won't let me archive it ...

So here's a copy

> Taken from: https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api#event-disconnect

| Reason | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `server namespace disconnect` | The socket was forcefully disconnected with socket.disconnect() |
| `client namespace disconnect` | The client has manually disconnected the socket using socket.disconnect() |
| `ping timeout` | The client did not send a PONG packet in the pingTimeout delay |
| `server shutting down` | The server is, well, shutting down |
| `transport error` | The connection has encountered an error |
| `transport close` | The connection was closed (example: the user has lost connection, or the network was changed from WiFi to 4G) |